# Access current category when editing cart

Tags: php, magento

Im successfylly accessing the default category ID (***5***) when on a product page (***view.phtml***). Using it to echo an important notice about custom made products:

```
if( Mage::app() -> getStore() -> getCode() == 'domain_com' ){

    if( Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory() == 5 || Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 5 || Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId() == 5 ){
        echo 'Important notice goes here...';
    }
}
```

When choosing to edit products in cart, the url change to, for example:  ***/checkout/cart/configure/id/10001/***, and the script stops working and only the half page is shown on to the screen. When I comment out the above code, the page (***view.phtml***) is running again.

How can I access the default product category when on ***/checkout/cart/configure/id/10001/***

Answer (score 0):

When editing a product from the cart there is no category. The product is independent.
You can get the product categories in that case like that.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryCollection();
```

Then loop through the `$categories` collection and pick the one you need.

**[EDIT]**
or like this

```
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$categoryIds));
```

Then loop through the `$categories`

Comment: Thanks @Marius - But is doesn't seem to work when running a foreach loop, it doesn't not return anything as far as I can see. Not from cart or from product page. No error message either.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work: exception `'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::addAttributeToSelect(Array
(
    [0] => *
)`

Comment: Is there a way to run my code ONLY when on a product page instead, with a IF-statement, and not show the notice when editing products added to cart?